# how to prevent postback on click of button in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview.I want to prevent loading of page again and again on click of edit,update and delete. When i click on edit to edit a row the page performs postback.So what i need to do in order to perform no postback.

```
My code is


     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "TestOrigin.aspx/BindDatatable",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json"

    });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function javascriptfunction()
    {
    return false;
    }
    </script>


<asp:ListView ID="lstOrigin" 
                        runat="server"  

  ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder1" OnItemEditing="EditListViewItem" 
        OnItemCanceling="CancelListViewItem"
         OnItemUpdating="UpdateListViewItem" 
         OnItemInserting="InsertListViewItem"
        InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnItemDeleting="DeleteListViewItem" 
DataKeyNames="ID" >

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr class="header">
                   <th >
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkID" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" 
CommandArgument="ID" Text="ID"   />
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkaddress" runat="server"   
 CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Address" Text="Address"  />
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkpin" runat="server" CommandName="Sort"  


CommandArgument="Pin" Text="Pin" />
                    </th>
                    <th >
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcity" runat="server" CommandName="Sort"  
CommandArgument="City" Text="City"  />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkstate" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" 
CommandArgument="State" Text="State" />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkcountry" runat="server" CommandName="Sort"   

 CommandArgument="Country" Text="Country"  />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkport" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" 
 CommandArgument="Port" Text="Port" />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkoutsource" runat="server" CommandName="Sort" 

CommandArgument="Outsourcing" Text="Outsourcing" />
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Modify
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="item">
            <td>
            <%# Eval("ID") %>
            </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Address") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Pin") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("City") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("State") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Country") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Port") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Outsourcing") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"    
PostBackUrl="~/TestOrigin.aspx" CommandName="Edit" OnClientClick="javascriptfunction"/>

                        <asp:Button ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
CommandName="Delete" ForeColor="Brown" OnClientClick="javascriptfunction"/>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td>
             <%# Eval("ID") %>
            </td>
               <td>
                    <%# Eval("Address") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Pin") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("City") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("State") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Country") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Port") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("Outsourcing") %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
CommandName="Edit" OnClientClick="javascriptfunction" />

                        <asp:Button ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
CommandName="Delete" ForeColor="Brown"  OnClientClick="javascriptfunction"/>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr class="edititem">

            <td>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Address") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pin") %>'   
/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>'  
 />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("State")   
%>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Country") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPort" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Port") %>'   
/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOutsource" runat="server" Text='<%# 
Eval("Outsourcing") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>

                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
CommandName="Update" OnClientClick=" javascriptfunction" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server"  Text="Cancel"  
CommandName="Cancel" OnClientClick="  javascriptfunction" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>

        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

put return before your function

```
OnClientClick="return javascriptfunction()"
```

and in java-script function at the end write

```
return false;
```

Comment: when i am adding OnClientClick="javascriptfunction(); return false;" then no postback occurs and no edit, delete,update are performed. How to solve this.

Comment: I you want to do it without post-back then you have to use jQuery Ajax for that

Comment: i had used jquery ajax and updated my code. please tell me why post back is occuring